# How to send one line at a packet using Gstreamer command line

Tags: udp, rtp, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to stream a raw video to ethernet via RTP Protocol (RFC4175), using Gstreamer 1.0 in Windows.

I don't want my data to be compressed, so I use rtpvrawpay element
I have the following gstreamer line

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=%FILENAME% ! videoparse width=%WIDTH% height=%HEIGHT% framerate=50/1 format=GST_VIDEO_FORMAT_GRAY16_BE ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,media=(string)video,encoding-name=(string)RAW,sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:2,witdh=640,height=512 ! rtpvrawpay pt=96 ! udpsink async=true host=%HOST% port=%PORT%
```

I have another system decoding this rtp video. However, that system is restricted to process 1 line of video for each UDP packet. Morever, the system eliminates any packet has a length different than 1342 bytes.
(1 line: 640(width)x2 bytes + 20 bytes of RTP Header + 42 bytes of UDP header)

So, I have to tell the gstreamer pipe to send 1 line at a packet. My first attempt was to set "mtu" property of the rtpvrawdepay element. When I set mtu to 1300, my UDP packets are 1400 bytes of length (?)

Then I set it to 1302, UDP packets are 1403 bytes. There has to be a way to tell gstreamer never use any packet as a continuation packet in RTP.

Answer (score 0):

some things to d0: first, upload the video to an FTP. Then, in JavaScript/html:

```
<embed src="myftpsie/mycoolvideo.mp4"></embed>
```

make sure its in a format the html can comprehend